# for every $n\ge{1} , \binom{2n}{n}\ge \frac{2^{2n}}{4\sqrt{n}+2} $

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inequality

Prove this inequality for every $n\ge{1}$

$$\binom{2n}{n}\ge \frac{2^{2n}}{4\sqrt{n}+2} $$

I try to prove it with simplification this inequality but i don't find right path to get solution.

Comment: from where comes this problem?

Comment: HINT: Call $a_n$ the LHS, and $b_n$ the RHS. Try to prove that for all $n$ you have $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \ge \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner(Iranian mathematics Society)IMS compilation

Comment: hello Amir, glad to see you

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner hello doctor ,nice to meet you to

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464721 for a proof using induction

Answer (score 0):

We begin with the product representations
$${2n\choose n}{1\over 2^{2n}}={1\over 2n}\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\left(1+{1\over 2j}\right)=\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1-{1\over2j}\right),\quad n\geq1.$$

From
$$ \prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\left(1+{1\over 2j}\right)^{\!\!2}=\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\left(1+{1\over j}+{1\over 4j^2}\right)\geq \prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\left(1+{1\over j}\right)=n,$$
we see that
$$\left({2n\choose n}{1\over 2^{2n}} \right)^{2} = {1\over (2n)^2}\, \prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\left(1+{1\over 2j}\right)^{\!\!2}
\geq {1\over 4n^2}\, n ={1\over 4n},\quad n\geq1.$$
 so by taking square roots, ${2n\choose n}{1\over 2^{2n}}\geq \displaystyle{1\over 2\sqrt{n}}\ge \frac{1}{4\sqrt{n}+2}.$