# How can the estimate $ \binom{n}{\frac {n}{2}} \ge \frac {2^n}{n+1} $be made?

Tags: inequality, induction, binomial-coefficients, estimation

Let's define the average value of binomial coefficients by $$
A (n) = \frac {1}{n+1} \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} 
$$
Clearly, $$A= \frac {2^n}{n+1} \qquad .$$ 
Now, this gives us the trivial estimate for $$ \binom{n}{\frac {n}{2}} $$ as
$$ \binom{n}{\frac {n}{2}} \ge \frac {2^n}{n+1}
$$
I know that the largest possible value of $\binom{n}{k}$ is at $k= \frac {n}{2}$

The estimate holds just because this largest value is greater than the average value of binomial coefficients?
Is it enough to say that this estimation holds since the maximum number in a set is always at least the average value?

Comment: What are you asking? Are you looking for a better estimate of $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$?

Comment: It is the largest term of $2^n=(1+1)^n=\sum_k\binom{n}{k}$. If the maximum term is smaller than $\frac{2^n}{n+1}$ then the whole sum is smaller than $2^n$.

Comment: The maximum number in a set is always at least the average value.

Comment: Hint: $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\geq \binom{n}{i}$ for all $i$.

Comment: Is it enough to say that this estimation holds since the maximum number in a set is always at least the average value.? @symplectomorphic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure that's valid! It's the same as saying
$$
\frac{2^n}{n+1} = \frac1{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}i\leq \frac1{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{n/2} = \frac{n+1}{n+1}\binom{n}{n/2} = \binom{n}{n/2}. 
$$

Comment: It's also valid $\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}<\frac{2^{n+1}}{n}$
I found expanding at infinity  this nice estimate, quite precise $\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}} \approx 2^n \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi  n}}$

Comment: @Raffaele There are even tighter bounds, as seen from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464721/proving-binom2nn-ge-frac22n-1-sqrtn?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

Just induction!

Firstly, we'll replace $n$ at $2n$.

Thus, we need to prove that $\binom{2n}{n}\geq\frac{2^{2n}}{2n+1}.$

For $n=1$ it's obvious.

Let $$\binom{2n}{n}\geq\frac{2^{2n}}{2n+1}.$$
Hence,$$\binom{2n+2}{n+1}=\binom{2n}{n}\cdot\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(n+1)^2}\geq\frac{2^{2n}}{2n+1}\cdot\frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1}=$$
$$=\frac{2^{2n+2}}{2n+3}\cdot\frac{2n+3}{2(n+1)}>\frac{2^{2n+2}}{2n+3}$$
and we are done!